# Thread pool queue with unique tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, java.util.concurrent

I'm using [ThreadPoolTaskExecutor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html) (of spring) in order to execute some tasks asynchronously.

The required task will load some object from an external DB into my system memory.
I'm using max thread pool size of 10 and max queue size of 100.

Suppose that all 10 threads are occupied getting objects from my DB and a task is created, it will go to the queue. Now another task is created that should get the same object (same key in DB) from the DB, it will also go to the queue (assuming all 10 threads are still occupied).

So my queue might get full easily with duplicated tasks which will get executed in turn and I don't want this to happen.

I thought that a solution should come in the form of a unique collection which serves as the thread pool queue.
Under the hood ThreadPoolTaskExecutor uses LinkedBlockingQueue which does not provide uniqueness.

I thought of a few possible solutions but none satisfies me:

- Using [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) instead of ThreadPoolTaskExecutor. The ThreadPoolExecutor provides a constructor which lets me determine the thread pool queue type, but it needs to implement the BlockingQueue interface. I could not find an implementation that preserve uniqueness.

This led me to try and extend [LinkedBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) and override add:

```
public boolean add(E e)
    if(!this.contains(e)) {
        return super.add(e);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But as far as I can tell this will lead to a major performance reduction since the `contains` method is limited by O(n) - bad idea.

What could solve my problem? I'm aiming for a good performance (in case of memory-performance trade offs I don't mind giving up memory for performance).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) and [ListenableFuture](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained) you could do something like that (haven't tested)

```
Set<String> uniqueQueue = Sets.newConcurrentHashSet();
ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 10, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Queues.newLinkedBlockingQueue(100));
ListeningExecutorService executorService = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(threadPoolExecutor);

String t1 = "abc";
if(uniqueQueue.add(t1)) {
    ListenableFuture<String> future = executorService.submit(() -> "do something with " + t1);
    Futures.addCallback(future, new FutureCallback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String result) {
            uniqueQueue.remove(t1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            uniqueQueue.remove(t1);
        }
    });
}
```

resulting in

- only items that are not currently being processed or in the queue will be added to the queue (`uniqueQueue`)
- items that have been processed will be removed from the `uniqueQueue`
- you'll only have a maxium of 100 items in the queue

this implementation does not handle

- `Exceptions` thrown by the `submit()` method
- Maximum number of items in the `unqiueQueue`

With reference to your requirement of loading objects from a database into memory, you might want to take a look at [Guava's Caches](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained).

**UPDATE**:

- [BlockingQueue backed by LinkedHashSet from Apache Marmotta project](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.marmotta/marmotta-core/3.3.0/org/apache/marmotta/platform/core/util/LinkedHashSetBlockingQueue.java/?v=source)

Comment: I already thought of using a workaround which is similar more or less to your suggestion (enforcing uniqueness using an additional set). If I will not get a better answer in the next days I will accept yours.

Comment: please let me know if you've come to a better solution in the next days.

Comment: i have just found a BlockingQueue implementation backed by a LinkedHashSet. Maybe this helps you: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.marmotta/marmotta-core/3.3.0/org/apache/marmotta/platform/core/util/LinkedHashSetBlockingQueue.java#LinkedHashSetBlockingQueue

Comment: I will have a look soon, the name sounds promissing and yes - this will defiantly help as you know well :)

Comment: Ok, I think you have provided me with all the possible solutions (Awesome!). The second one (using LinkedHashSetBlockingQueue with ThreadPoolExecutor) is very elegant but it might not be complete since still a few similar tasks can run at the same time (in the case of less than 10 running threads, no need in queue in such a case). Your first solution is "less elegant" but does the job perfectly. What do you think?

Comment: "less elegant" still means "elegant" =) i like the additional layer of abstraction, one could easily encapsulate this functionality by implementing the ExecutorService interface providing this new type (or ForwardingExecutorService from Guava). as long as there is a way to write an elegant unit test I consider this approach to be clean =)

Comment: This solution could be implemented in the same way but without Guava and ListenableFuture. You can just override `afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t)` method from ThreadPoolExecutor and do the same thing.

Comment: I ended up extending ThreadPoolTaskExecutor (of spring) and overriding the "execute" method.

Comment: @forhas Even though you've accepted this answer, I believe it would be helpful to add another answer with details about your final solution.

Comment: @forhas Can you share your implementation? I have the same problem, and don't want to use Guava.

Comment: @user1480019 I just posted an answer, it basically does the same thing as the accepted answer but based on spring libraries instead of Guava.

Answer (score 1):

A solution similar to the accepted solution but based on Spring (as opposed to Guava):

Create interface **RunnableWithId**:

```
 public interface RunnableWithId extends Runnable {

    /**
     * @return A unique id for this task
     */
    String getTaskId();
}
```

Create another interface **TaskWithIdExecutor**:

```
import org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor;


public interface TaskWithIdExecutor extends TaskExecutor {

    /**
     * Executes the given task if it is not queued or already running
     *
     * @param task The task to execute
     */
    void executeIfNotQueuedOrRunningAlready(RunnableWithId task);
}
```

Create your custom executor **UniquTaskExecutor**:

```
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;
import org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFutureCallback;

import java.util.Set;

/**
 * In addition to all the abilities of ThreadPoolTaskExecutor adds the ability
 * to execute a task only if it is not already running/queued using the
 * executeIfNotQueuedOrRunningAlready method.
 *
 * @see ThreadPoolTaskExecutor
 */
public class UniquTaskExecutor extends ThreadPoolTaskExecutor implements TaskWithIdExecutor {

    private Set<String> queuedTasks;

    public UniquTaskExecutor() {
        queuedTasks = Sets.newConcurrentHashSet();
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable task) {
        super.execute(task);
    }

    /**
     * @param task The task to execute
     */
    @Override
    public void executeIfNotQueuedOrRunningAlready(RunnableWithId task) {
        if (queuedTasks.add(task.getTaskId())) {
            ListenableFuture<?> res = submitListenable(task);
            res.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<Object>() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                    queuedTasks.remove(task.getTaskId());
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Object o) {
                    queuedTasks.remove(task.getTaskId());
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Use the **executeIfNotQueuedOrRunningAlready** method of **UniquTaskExecutor** to achieve uniqueness in task executions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed to manage the database, I'd suggest using the database itself to prevent duplicate effort:

- Add a lockid column to your table
- Add a status column to your table (maybe 'new' and 'done')
- Make sure your DB isolation level is at least READ_COMMITTED

Then try something like this, in your main thread:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int lockId = rand.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1) + 1;
String update = "UPDATE DB.Table SET lockid=" + lockId + " WHERE lockid=0 AND status='new' " // + AND your conditions + LIMIT ##
String select = "SELECT * FROM DB.Table WHERE lockid=" + lockId;
// now execute those sql statements with QueryRunner or whatever you use in-house
```

The rows that return from the select are what you add to the queue.

Then, you have a class that implements Runnable that processes those rows, by retrieving them from the queue.  Once it processes a row, you do another SQL update (inside the Runnable) to set the lockId back to zero and set the status to 'done'.

This has the advantage of working even if you have multiple machines each with their own queue.

Comment: Who said I'm using a relational DB (I'm not)? And I'm not looking for a DB optimization solution, it could be any type of task running there (accessing a DB is just a private case).

Comment: That's fair; I was just going on what I saw in your question ("will load some object from an external DB").  What I wrote could also apply to non-RDB, depending on your consistency settings.

Comment: The title of the questions is "Thread pool queue with unique tasks". You sure had good intentions but I think you missed a bit. Thank you for sharing anyway :)